# R map function related query

Tags: r

## values variable is used here: How exactly is ~.x applied in R ??

```
values <- list(
A = c(9, 1, 8, 4, 3), B = c(7,  3,  4,  4,  1,  1, 10,  8))
map(values, ~.x + 5)
```

Comment: Code works fine.......please help me understand it!!!!1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.x` is each of the vector elements of the `list` object 'values'

```
map(values, ~ .x + 5)
```

The `~` is anonymous lambda function in tidyverse construct.  It can be otherwise changed to

```
map(values, function(x) x + 5)
```

Comment: Why do we need ~ symbol ?

Comment: @bsb426 it is terse representation for the lambda function call in tidyverse

Comment: @bsb426 if you have used `python`, the call is different `lambda x: x + 5`

Comment: Can I use lapply here? instead of map

Comment: @bsb426 yes, just do `lapply(values, function(x) x + 5)